# Linux Mint: Hibernate does not work

Tags: linux-mint, hibernate, pm-utils

I have tried hibernate multiple times on my Linux Mint 14. It does not seem to work. I have added some log which I think may be useful. Can someone help me diagnose the problem?

laptop model:
    I: TOSHIBA Satellite R630/Portable PC, BIOS Version 1.90   02/24/2011

/var/log/syslog

```
Feb 21 21:21:51 kernel: [ 3526.006366] PM: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0009e000-0x000fffff]
Feb 21 21:21:51 kernel: [ 3526.006372] PM: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb70d0000-0xffffffff]
Feb 21 21:21:51 kernel: [ 3526.007297] PM: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x1fc000000-0x1ffffffff]
Feb 21 21:21:51 kernel: [ 3526.007556] PM: Basic memory bitmaps created
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.


Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    7.877813] EXT4-fs (sda5): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    7.877817] EXT4-fs (sda5): write access will be enabled during recovery
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    8.833136] EXT4-fs (sda5): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    8.833146] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262260
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    8.833177] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262215
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    8.833216] EXT4-fs (sda5): 2 orphan inodes deleted
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    8.833217] EXT4-fs (sda5): recovery complete
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [    8.920573] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Feb 21 21:23:00 kernel: [   19.912627] Adding 14680060k swap on /dev/mapper/vgroup1-swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:14680060k
```

hibernate module:

```
$ dpkg -l | g pm-utils
ii  pm-utils                                    1.4.1-9                                   all          utilities and scripts for power management
```

swap

```
# swap on logical volume
/dev/vgroup1/swap                         none            swap    sw              0       0


Disk /dev/mapper/vgroup1-swap: 15.0 GB, 15032385536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1827 cylinders, total 29360128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

/var/log/pm_suspend.log

```
Thu Feb 21 21:21:50 GMT 2013: Running hooks for hibernate.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate:
...
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager hibernate hibernate:
Having NetworkManager put all interaces to sleep...Failed.
...
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant hibernate hibernate:
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please post the output of the following command: `cat /sys/power/state`. Maybe the system doesn't allow you to save to disk.

Answer (score 5):

I have similar issues with Xubuntu and the wpa_supplicant service, basically, if I suspend/hibernate once, it works, if I try it a second time (without rebooting) it hangs, I get that message, then it returns to login.

Turns out there is a [bug with that portion of Network Manager](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1007924), luckily there is a workaround/fix:

> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager resume suspend_hybrid:  Having NetworkManager wake interfaces back
>   up...Failed.
>
> Looking at the script is uses org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep and
>   org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wake.
>
> Calling this results in errors like this:  % sudo dbus-send
>   --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep 
>   Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "sleep" with
>   signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" doesn't
>   exist
>
> According to the documentation [[1]](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/spec.html), the interface is different / has
>   changed.
>
> The correct usage would be to call
>   org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Sleep with a boolean value, like:
>
> sudo dbus-send --print-reply --system
>   --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Sleep boolean:true

So modify the file: `gksudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager`

Find the part that says:

`org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep`

and change to

`org.freedesktop.Networkmanager.Sleep boolean:true`

Then find the part that says

`org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wake` and change to

`org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Sleep boolean:false`

Not sure if that will work for you.. but its worth a shot!