# How to find reason a notebook wakes up?

Tags: power-management, suspend

I'm having a problem with my notebook suspending, but then waking up when I don't want it to (either immediately, or much later when in the bag - I may have two issues to solve here). But for the moment this question is about troubleshooting: is there a command I can run that will tell me what the trigger was for the last `resume` action? E.g. whether a key was pressed, or the power button, whether it was a wake-on-lan signal, whether it was switching from AC power to batter, etc, etc.

It appears that on Windows you can type `powercfg -lastwake` to find this out. So I'm looking for the Linux equivalent of that command.

If there is no such command, what do I need to look for, in which log file?

(Mint 16, xfce, Lenova Thinkpad, kernel 3.11.0-12-generic)

Comment: Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/297057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've got a ThinkPad, besides the other suggestions (preliminary the `systemd` hint), if you're using the `thinkpad_acpi` driver, you might want to have a look at `/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/wakeup_reason`.  This file contains a number telling you whether the embedded controller woke up your laptop for reasons like <del>low battery</del> (at least I thought it did), dock-removal request, etc.

As [`Documentation/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.txt) states:

```
wakeup_reason:
    Set to 1 if the system is waking up because the user
    requested a bay ejection.  Set to 2 if the system is
    waking up because the user requested the system to
    undock.  Set to zero for normal wake-ups or wake-ups
    due to unknown reasons.
```

Answer (score 10):

For the sake of completeness, there is another solution mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/816336) to a similar question.

Awakened by power button:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep Wake-up
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
```

Awakened by RTC clock:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep Wake-up
    Wake-up Type: APM Timer
```

Awakened by keyboard:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep Wake-up
    Wake-up Type: PCI PME#
```

Comment: I made this answer a community wiki as all credit goes to the original answer linked above. If you upvote this answer, please consider upvoting the original one as well.

Answer (score 5):

#### Systems with systemd

On systems that make use of `systemd` you can look  through systemd's log using the `journalctl` command.

#### Example

Here, for example my system went to sleep from the lid being closed and then when I opened it, you'd see events related to this like so:

```
$ journalctl | less
...
May 19 09:04:47 greeneggs.bubba.net kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
May 19 09:04:47 greeneggs.bubba.net kernel: PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
May 19 09:33:42 greeneggs.bubba.net kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
May 19 09:33:42 greeneggs.bubba.net systemd[1]: Time has been changed
May 19 09:33:42 greeneggs.bubba.net systemd-logind[772]: Lid opened.
...
```

#### Systems without systemd

For systems that do not use `systemd` you have a variety of places to look. You could for starters look in the `dmesg` log. You could also look in `/var/log/syslog` for messages related to power management or ACPI related events.

I would start by taking a look in `/var/log/pm_suspend.log`, assuming it exists. Especially on distros such as Linux Mint, you'll likely find messages like this there:

```
Thu Feb 21 21:21:50 GMT 2013: Running hooks for hibernate.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate:
...
```

#### References

- [Systemd woes](http://blog.chrisolin.com/index.php/systemd-woes/)
- [systemd - ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd)
- [Linux Mint: Hibernate does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65816/linux-mint-hibernate-does-not-work)

Comment: But, systemd isn't default in Mint or Debian. It's only included as a preview in Debian-stable currently.

Comment: @GuyHughes - yes I know, I'm looking for the way to do this under previous versions.

Comment: systemd recorded the procedure of waking up, but didn't record the reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can start with `dmesg`, check `man dmesg` but you might want to try `dmesg -k`.

Comment: `dmesg -k | wc -l` gives 3298 :-)  BTW, does this tell me something different to looking at `/var/log/kern.log` ?

Comment: @DarrenCook just identify when the suspend/resume happened and analyse that section which will `wc -l` to much less.